# Kohana Database query in a view file

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

I am using gallery3 which is written in kohana framework. I want to execute database query in a theme view file. the page output stops when it is encountering the query.

Link- http://techmax.co.in/movie/gallery3/index.php/Ye-Maaya-Chesave-Movie

```
$curr_url = url::current();
    $exp= explode('/',$curr_url);
    if (preg_match("/\bMovie\b/i","$curr_url")){
        $query = mysql_query ( "SELECT name,id FROM movies WHERE gallery LIKE '%$exp[0]%' ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);  ?>
    <font size="+2"><a href="http://techmax.co.in/movie/movies.php?mov_no=<? echo $row[1]; ?>"><? echo $row[0] ?> Movie Page</a></font>  <?  }
    else if(preg_match("/\bStar\b/i","$curr_url")){
        $query = mysql_query ( "SELECT name,id FROM stars WHERE gallery LIKE '%$exp[0]%' ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);  ?>
    <font size="+2"><a href="http://techmax.co.in/movie/stars.php?star_no=<? echo $row[1]; ?>"><? echo $row[0] ?> Star Page</a></font> <? }
        ?>
```

This code is in the page gallery3/themes/wind/views/page.html.php

If the query executes correctly there should be some text behind the movie page link at top right corner

Comment: Very nice page. And the code??? We're good here, but we're not *that* good...

Comment: What DB extension are you using? MySQL? If so, why is the query done as a method call from an object (`$db->query`)? Are you possibly mixing up MySQL and MySQLi code?

Comment: sry i was trying some things(updated code) this is the original code that went good in localserver

Comment: It seems like a Fatal error is being raised somewhere - check your Apache logs, or if you can't get at them/don't know what you're looking for, call `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script, and you should get an error message that will give you a clue where to start...

Comment: Sorry, but this code is an ugly mess. Try to separate logic from presentation by doing all the database queries in the models and pass the data through to the view.

Comment: I am not using it to develop the site the gallery is written in kohana. I am using the gallery for my site. I want to direct the people to the main site once they are in gallery to the respective film page.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing all your `<?` tags to `<?php` tags instead. Many servers are configured to disallow the short opening tags to avoid confusion with `<?xml` declarations.

If your page works on your test server but not on live, there is a good chance this is at least one of the problems.

Also, verify that you MySQL actually connected successfully...